# Delete ec2 volume via aws java sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, command-line-interface, volume

I wanted to delete AWS EC2 volumes which were attached to instances.

But, I could not find any implementation in AWS's java sdk to do so.

Its equivalent cli command is : 
/usr/bin/aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id $volumeId

But I want to do it via java sdk.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`deleteVolume(DeleteVolumeRequest request)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#deleteVolume-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DeleteVolumeRequest-):

> Deletes the specified EBS volume. The volume must be in the available state (not attached to an instance).

See also: [`DeleteVolume` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteVolume.html)